# Making 2D array not have a fixed number of indexes

Tags: java, arrays

I have this 2D array `[[1, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0], [3, 4, 5,], [6, 7, 0], null, [0, 0, 0]]`.

I want to turn it into a dynamic array, meaning I want it to be `[[1], [2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7], null, []]`.

Below is my code for trying it out. I can't seem to get it. Any suggestions?

```
public static int[][] getNonFixedArray(String string) {

    String[] split = string.split("\\|", -1);
    int[][] result = new int[split.length][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        int[] array = getNonFixedArray(split[i]);

        if (array != null) {

            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                result[i][j] = array[j];

                if (result[i][j] == 0) {
                    result[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(" ");
                }
            }
        } else {
            result[i] = null;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you go through you inner arrays (the second for loop), you are trying to replace the element with value '0' with `Integer.parseInt(" ");`. This will probably give you an exception anyway. What might help you is to collect the non-zero numbers (in a list if you can use list) and create an array based on that after the second for loop ends.